# cassandra running multiple apps

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have been playing with Cassandra and I really like the dynamics in how it handles nodes.

The question: I have more than one app, where I would like to use Cassandra as db. That is many keyspaces. Is it advisable to have multiple apps using the same cassandra cluster?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run as many apps as you wish. The capacity of the cluster does not depend on the number of apps or keyspaces.